Build static zlib for Android
I'm using the following script. It should produce static lib. However, it produces both libz.a and libz.so.
(I have -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF specified.)
How can I set it to produce static libs only?
#!/bin/sh
set -e

ZLIB_VERSION=1.3.1
VERSIONED_ZLIB=zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION
VERSIONED_ZLIB_FILE=$VERSIONED_ZLIB.tar.gz

MY_PWD=$PWD

echo "zlib version $ZLIB_VERSION"

if ! test -f $VERSIONED_ZLIB_FILE; then
    echo "Downloading..."
    curl -O https://www.zlib.net/$VERSIONED_ZLIB_FILE
fi

if ! test -d $VERSIONED_ZLIB; then 
    echo "Extracting..."
    tar -xvzf $VERSIONED_ZLIB_FILE
fi

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/
ANDROID_API=23

for arch in "x86" "x86_64" "arm64" "arm"
do
    MY_VERSIONED_ZLIB=VERSIONED_ZLIB_$arch
    rm -rf $MY_VERSIONED_ZLIB
    cp -r $VERSIONED_ZLIB $MY_VERSIONED_ZLIB

    case $arch in
        arm)
            ANDROID_API=23
        ARCH_PATH=armeabi-v7a
            ;;
        x86)
            ANDROID_API=23
        ARCH_PATH=x86
            ;;
        arm64)
            ANDROID_API=23
        ARCH_PATH=arm64-v8a
            ;;
        x86_64)
            ANDROID_API=23
        ARCH_PATH=x86_64
            ;;
    esac

    ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=""
    for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86"
    do
        if [ -d "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$host/bin" ]; then
            ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$host/bin"
            break
        fi
    done

    export PATH="$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN":"$PATH"

    MY_PREFIXDIR=$PWD/prebuilt/android/$ARCH_PATH
    rm -rf $MY_PREFIXDIR

    cd $MY_VERSIONED_ZLIB

    MY_CMAKE_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=$ARCH_PATH -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=$ANDROID_API"
    MY_CMAKE_FLAGS="$MY_CMAKE_FLAGS -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_PREFIXDIR -B bld"

    cmake $MY_CMAKE_FLAGS
    cmake --build bld --config Release --target install
   
    cd $MY_PWD
    rm -rf $MY_VERSIONED_ZLIB
done

rm -rf $VERSIONED_ZLIB
rm $VERSIONED_ZLIB_FILE

echo Done.


Can you please explain static libs ?

The CMakeLists.txt in zlib does not support building a static library only (or a shared library
only). Neither does the makefile generated by ./configure for an autotools build. However
the build is very cheap and you could edit the CMakeLists.txt on the lines of
zdenop's patch here to remove
zlib (the shared library) from the installed targets. (Not tested by me).
